# Application Issues in Migrating Websphere from 8.0.0.10 to Liberty profile

Tags: websphere, websphere-8, websphere-liberty

i'm trying to migrate WAS server 8.0.0.10 to Liberty Profile.  So I downloaded the Migration Tool using the "Install New Software" option in the "Help" Menu just a week ago. I selected the "Migration Tools" -> "Websphere Application Server Migration" -> "Configuration Manager" -> "Websphere Configuration Migration Toolkit for Websphere". Followed below link steps http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/library/techarticles/1404_vines2/1404_vines2.html . But while executing comments in command prompt:

```
wsadmin -lang jython -c "AdminTask.extractConfigProperties(['-propertiesFileName my.props'])"
```

Getting Below error message :

```
C:\Users\DSIVARAM\WAS-profiles\8.0\SFQ\bin>wsadmin(.sh/.bat) -lang jython -c "AdminTask.extractConfigProperties(['-propertiesFileName my.props'])"
WASX7209I: Connected to process "SFQ" on node SFQNode using SOAP connector;  The type of process is: UnManagedProcess
WASX7411W: Ignoring the following provided option: [(.sh/.bat)]
WASX7015E: Exception running command: "AdminTask.extractConfigProperties(['-propertiesFileName my.props'])"; exception information:
 com.ibm.ws.management.wasresource.common.WASResourceException: com.ibm.ws.management.wasresource.common.WASResourceException: com.ibm.ws.management.wasresource.common.WASResourceException: com.ibm.websphere.management.exception.AdminException: 
ADMA0144E: Application SourcingForQuality20031104 is installed with the zero binary copy option. Applications are installed using this option in a Rational unit test environment or using AppManagement MBean API. 
When an application is installed using this option it is not possible to perform any operation on this application using wsadmin or administrative console that involves accessing the application metadata or EAR file.  
Such operations include view/edit application information, export, export DDL etc.  The only possible operations using wsadmin or admin console are start, stop and uninstall. 
If this application is installed using WSAD unit test environment then use WSAD to view/edit application information.
```

Please help me to sort out the issue.

Comment: Leave out `(.sh/.bat)`, try just this: `wsadmin -lang jython -c "AdminTask.extractConfigProperties(['-propertiesFileName my.props'])"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running your server from development tool (Eclipse/Rad), change your server publishing settings from `run resources from workspace` to `run from server` , restart and redeploy application. You should be able to export then.

Comment: Thanks Gas :) Properties file getting created.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to extract application information with extractConfigProperties if you have a zero-binary installed application. I think you can limit the extent of the extract using the -filterMechanism or -configData options to just extract the configuration needed by the application without extracting the application information itself.

See http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/txml_7extractprops.html for examples.